# Foreach loop with if statement ERROR

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

So I figured I would paste the whole thing, but the foreach loop section isn't working. This is for an add page, and when I publish it and try to search, this is the error page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMxJh.png. Also, this is what the add page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQLSE.png.
Referring to the error page, it says "incorrect syntax near "("". Does anyone know how to fix this?

- I did originally not have a space before "VALUES" in the query, so that would've been an issue but it isn't anymore
- I believe that the issue lies within the logic, or something very small with the formatting that I'm not aware of
- I also did not copy and paste this code - it was given to me like this, and my task is to find out how it works and add comments. I'm also supposed to fix this error, which lies in the foreach loop I believe. I don't know c# well enough to know what the error could be
- Added comma before GETDATE()

  ```
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
          // create new Sql connection
          SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
          connection.Open();


          // insert into query
          string query = "INSERT INTO license_info (SoftwareTitle, SoftwareVersion, SoftwareVendor, SoftwareLastUpdate)";
          query += " VALUES (";

          // first is a true boolean statement
          // if bool not first, then false
          bool first = true;


          // might not need this (foreach loop). if not listed first, add key + -@
          foreach (string key in context.Request.Form.AllKeys)
          {
              // add comma (,) if not first
              if (!first)
              {
                  query += ", ";
              }

              query += "@" + key;
              first = false;

          }
          // if not listed first, apply GETDATE() function
          if (!first)
          {
              query += ", GETDATE());";
          }


          first = false;



          SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

          foreach (string key in context.Request.Form.AllKeys)
          {
              command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + key, context.Request.Form[key]);
          }

          command.ExecuteNonQuery();

          connection.Close();

      // end connection
      // connection.Close();

      // redirect to admin
      context.Response.Redirect(Properties.Settings.Default.BaseURL + @"/admin");
  }
  ```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the SQL query that you create?

Comment: Yeah - don't copy and paste code without thinking. You need to check each line of code and make sure it's doing what you want.

Comment: Show us the value of `query` that is being sent

Comment: It looks like you're actually missing a comma before the `GETDATE()` call

Comment: FYI Even though you are using SQL parameters you are still at risk for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Added some notes to my original post. Also, how do I find the value of the query?

Comment: _how do I find the value of the query?_ - use the debugger. Add a break point and then look at the value of `query`.

Comment: Apologies, could someone explain in details/steps on how to find the value of the query? I've never used the debugger before (I'm a student, haven't covered this yet) so I really have no idea what I'm doing, and Google wasn't much help

Answer (score 1):

This can greatly be simplified by using the known form keys to get the values. There is no need for looping or building a dynamic query of any sort.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // create new Sql connection
    const string query = "INSERT INTO license_info (SoftwareTitle, SoftwareVersion, SoftwareVendor, SoftwareLastUpdate) VALUES (@SoftwareTitle, @SoftwareVersion, @SoftwareVendor, @SoftwareLastUpdate)";
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        // todo: Update the SqlDbTypes and length according to your schema
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SoftwareTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200)).Value = context.Request.Form["TitleKey"];
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SoftwareVersion", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200)).Value = context.Request.Form["VersionKey"];
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SoftwareVendor", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200)).Value = context.Request.Form["VendorKey"];
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SoftwareLastUpdate", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = DateTime.Now;
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Also you should use `using` blocks to wrap the types that implement `IDisposable`, in this case it will always ensure the database connection is closed even if there is an Exception.